# Publishing hystrix metrics to API

Tags: netflix, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a web service running as multiple docker containers. The docker hosts are  not under my control. I use hystrix to record metrics.  I thought of using Turbine to monitor the metrics. But i do not have access to the real hostnames and ports of my we app instances to give Turbine. So I am thinking of a push model where the individual instances of my web app publishes the metrics to another API on which i can run dadhboard tools. I looked at Servo, but it also does not suite my needs as it publishes to JMX.   Can I use custom publisher for this? Are there examples for this use case?

Comment: Are you using Eureka in your infrastructure?

Comment: No. We use consul.

Comment: Have you tried using turbine.appConfig property, defining application names? I assume that if you are using service discovery in docker-based environment and services can talk to each other, IP resolution problem must have ben already resolved.